# JAXB performance significantly degrading when under load

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb

We have a bunch of micro-services that use JAXB to marshal/un-marshal between between XML payloads and Java objects.
Part of our load tests we noticed significant performance degradation and after putting lots of log entries in place we found out that JAXB processing (mainly un-marshal part) sometimes it takes 1 to 3 mills (as it should) but sometimes it takes seconds (even 10 to 20s) to process basically the same payload (only a few element values are different to make them unique. Payloads are not small but not huge either; around 50KB.

When not under load the processing is always fast. My only one suspicion (without any research about how JAXB internally works) is that there are some `syncronized` calls and with lots of threads doing the same thing in parallel it just bottle neck the whole thing.

This is how we un-marshal:

```
public MyJavaObject toMyJavaObject(String payload) {
    try (StringReader reader = new StringReader(payload)) {
       final StreamSource source = new StreamSource(reader);
       return (MyJavaObject) ((JAXBElement) myMarshaller.unmarshal(source)).getValue();
    }
 }
```

Where `myMarshaller` bean is created like below:

```
@Value("classpath:my/path/MyJavaObject.xsd")
private Resource myJavaObjectSchema;

@Bean
@Qualifier("myMarshaller")
public Jaxb2Marshaller myMarshaller() {
   final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
   marshaller.setSchemas(myJavaObjectSchema);
   marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(MyJavaObject.class, JAXBElement.class);
   marshaller.setCheckForXmlRootElement(false);
   return marshaller;
}
```

So my question is what is causing such a big performance impact or how could we find where the issue is. The difference between 2 mills and 20 seconds is huge and why such a difference when the payloads are structural identical. Is there something to watch for or a way to fix it? Also if the worst comes worst is there a better JAXB alternative. We also use JAXB for schema validation and it is important object hitting up our systems to comply with the industry standards.

Our JAXB classes are part of spring-oxm-5.3.27.jar which in turn will use `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1`

** UPDATE **
I changed the parser to no longer be a Spring bean but rather create a new marshaller instance for every message being un-marshalled and the performance degraded even more:

```
parse 'Time taken to parse my request: *, client reference id: *' AS duration, clientReferenceId
| filter @message like 'Time taken to parse my request:'
| stats avg(duration)
Showing 1 of 9,831 records matched
12650.4609

parse 'Time taken to parse my request: *, client reference id: *' AS duration, clientReferenceId
| filter @message like 'Time taken to parse my request:'
| sort duration asc
  duration    clientReferenceId
1       16    OHaRPFh7Z2USRpfveFfB7NE1OEdU
2       16    3Xo1n6nZsrBtfROsRlh3N2rZHKK4

parse 'Time taken to parse my request: *, client reference id: *' AS duration, clientReferenceId
| filter @message like 'Time taken to parse my request:'
| sort duration desc
  duration    clientReferenceId
1   124585    Oj8L3Vt9dzDuWBb4wXv7yaUiv
2   120226    c972mxd544fjXqXIDp3DdPLP9
```

Comment: Your JAXB classes aren't part of Spring, only the `Jaxb2Marshaller` is part of Spring. JAXB is a separate dependency. You can try a newer version (not too new as that is for JakartaEE and not JavaEE). Else dig further into JAXB and see what is taking so long.

Comment: Yes you are right. I only provided that as an entry point in the dependency tree. jaxb library is `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1`. I updated my question to specify this.

Comment: How is this method being called? If this is from a controller you can just use `@RequestBody` and Spring will do the marshalling.

Comment: How are you testing this? Is the entity making unmarshal requests in a different process or in the same process as the unmarshaller? Make sure that the 10-20s your're seeing is really from unmarshalling and not from, say, thread starvation or GC pauses. Did you profile memory during the load test?

Comment: @Deinum No controller is involved here.  Everything is background processing. The XML message arrives either in a Kafka topic or in a JMS queue as a String body. Apart from setting some variables with no resource access the method we log in and log out does not do anything other than un-marshal call. I can move the log calls to `toMyJavaObject` but i don't think it will make any difference. This is especially valid as once I replayed the un-marshal with some xPath manipulation to extract the values I was interested in the issue went away so yes the JAXB was the culprit.

Comment: But why sometimes takes 2 mills to do it and sometimes (lots of times) takes seconds

Comment: @BorisB. it it was GC I doubt it would happen so frequent. I adjusted the CPU and the memory of that container to much higher than needed values before publishing this question. The issue is strictly happening when a lot of parallel processing is happening.

Comment: You can use the same technology for message listeners, they marshalling will be done automatically (and will save memory as well). One thing is that you are passing a schema, which triggers validation. When using XPath i doubt there is validation. So i would check what happens without the schema.

Comment: @Julian Also, my Spring is rusty, but IIRC the default bean scope is singleton, and (again IIRC) JAXB marshalers are not reentrant and thread-safe. I don't see the full code above, is the same `myMarshaller` instance used for all unmarshalling? If so, can you try with a transient scope (new-instance-per-call)?

Comment: Yes `myMarshaller` is a singleton and it is for sure used by all unmarshall calls. Not hard to create a new instance every time is used. I'll do and update on here. The change is very easy, but I might not get an environment to test immediately, so my update might come with a bit of delay.

Comment: I changed the code to always create a new JAXB marshaller before using it and I can confirm things got even worse: the minimum parsing time jumped from 2 mills to 16 mills while the maximum jumped to 101 seconds. Question updated.

Comment: @Julian I only realized now that your marshaller is Spring's `Jaxb2Marshaller`, not  the xml.bind one. The spring one is indeed thread-safe as it's creating a new instance for each unmarshal. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-oxm/src/main/java/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.java#L795

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve this issue? If yes, I think it deserves an explanation. It's  very interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. As soon as we switched to XPath way and the issue went away our project managers closed the issue and moved the focus on something else. My gut feeling is that is a muti threading issue.

Answer (score 1):

We made similar observations: the more threads we throw at JAXB with schema validation enabled, the worse it performs. In our case, lock contention was clearly visible in the thread view of profilers (like VisualVM) and we were able to track it down to the `synchronized` method `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance()` which is called for every marshalling/unmarshalling. We reported this as a [bug to OpenJDK](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8320602).

Note that the [Xerces2 library](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) (which is where JDK's XML parser/validator implementation originates from) has fixed this issue [in the year 2007](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=558582) (!). You could try using this instead (just add the dependency, it is picked up by the ServiceLoader mechanism automagically) - in our case, it 100% solved the issue.

Comment: Looks like something we should look into. Pls give me a bit of time. I need to reactivate this issue. It is worth trying because by now it only happens in a test environment while stressing the system. It is just a matter of time when the issue pops up in prod.

Comment: @Julian note that the JDK bug mentioned in my answer has already been fixed, but it is unclear whether users of Java 17 or 21 will get the fix...